# Where did they get the children's artwork used for Captain Picard Day?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard, props

The *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode “The Pegasus” opens with Picard, Riker, and Troi in the conference room viewing and discussing a variety of artwork that in the episode were supposed to be entries in an art contest for Captain Picard Day. The artwork appears to me likely to have been made by actual children rather than adult propmakers trying to make props that looked like they could have been made by children. Therefore, I've long wondered where these art projects came from. Were they made by actual children? And if so, were these children related to the production crew, or perhaps they were fanart made by child fans of the show?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [Star Trek TNG Companion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Companion), the artwork was sourced from two local schools and [Alan Sims](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alan_Sims)' children.

> Contest winner Paul Menegay was named for a friend of Brannon
>   Braga’s, although **the entries actually came from two area elementary
>   schools and prop man Alan Sims’ own children.**

Comment: I worked in the art department of a TV show and that's what we did for one episode featuring an elementary school classroom–various members of the crew had their kids do drawings.  We still needed a few to fill out the wall space, so I did the rest.  Drawing with my off-hand with a totally unclenched frame of mind did the trick well enough.